# Is it possible to have multiple strings in one position of an array?

Tags: javascript

For example if my array is

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var answer = cars[1];
```

and I create a function where if I type 'Volvo' it says 'Correct'. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo|volkswagen", "BMW"];
```

So when I type what is at position 1, I can type Volvo or volkswagen and it will say 'correct'? (But not both)

Comment: Can you show the code of your function, so we can say where to adapt it?

Comment: but why you are  not using object to store multiple values in one position ?

Comment: What is your use case for needing to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You define a multi dimensional array.

```
var cars = [["Saab"], ["Volvo", "volkswagen"], ["BMW"]];
if(cars[1].includes(val)){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the second array inside the first one:

```
var cars = ["Saab", ["Volvo", "Volkswagen"], "BMW"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method( with seperator `|` ) and check value using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```
// split the string by `|`  symbol
var answer = cars[1].split('|');

// check value by checking index in array
if(answer.indexOf(val) > -1){
   // do the rest here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split element at `|` and use `includes` to check value.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo|volkswagen", "BMW"];

function check(value, pos) {
  return cars[pos].split('|').includes(value)
}

console.log(check('Volvo', 1))
console.log(check('volkswagen', 1))
console.log(check('Saab', 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object instead of an array for fast lookup (which `includes` and `indexOf` do not do):

```
var cars = { 
    "Saab": 0, 
    "Volvo": 1,
    "volkswagen": 1,
    "BMW": 2
};
```

Your check would run in constant time:

```
if (cars[answer] === 1) // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an hash object:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo|volkswagen", "BMW"];

cars=cars.reduce(function(obj,el,i){
    obj[i]=el.split("|");
    return obj;
},{});

console.log("cars is",cars);

var guess=prompt("what is at 1?");

if(cars[1].includes(guess)){
  alert("right"); 
}else{ 
    alert("wrong");
}
```

So now cars is like:

```
cars[1]===["Volvo","volkswagen"];
```

So you can check if this Array has "volkswagen in it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```js
function check( array, position, value){
        var values = array[position].split('|');
        if(values.indexOf(value) >= 0)
            alert("Right");
        else alert("wrong");
    }
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo|volkswagen", "BMW"];
    value = prompt("What is the value at position 1 ");
    check(cars, 1, value );
```